# wysiwyg in rules text field

Tags: rules, wysiwyg

I've got some rules sending email messages to users. The content of the email is defined in a field in a 'send mail' action and I were wondering if it's possible to use wysiwyg there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. You can use [`hook_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7) to change any field into text area into a WYSIWYG field:

```
function MYMODULE_form_rules_ui_edit_element_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  //Set the type to text format
  $form['parameter']['message']['settings']['message']['#type'] = 'text_format';

  //Replace 'full_html' with 'filtered_html' or any other input format that has a WYSIWYG profile
  $form['parameter']['message']['settings']['message']['#format'] = 'full_html'; 
}
```